# How to create reusable components using page objects

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

I have a text box spinner control and some validations against it.

This text box spinner control is used in n number of pages where I need to check for same validations.

So I would like to create a page spinnertextbox.js and call this in other pages. 
So my confusion is how to I access this spinnertextbox.js from test spec files.

Test spec - > Pages -> spinnertextbox.js

Do I call the spinnertextbox.js directly from Testspec (which I feel is wrong).
I tried the following to follow the flow of Test spec to Pages and from Pages to spinnertextbox.js

Below is what I have implemented.

Spinnertextbox.js`

```
var txtbox = function () {


this.Up = function (upArrow) {
    upArrow.click();
};


this.Down = function (downArrow) {
    downArrow.click();
};
};

module.exports =  txtbox;
```

Homepage.js – which is going to call the spinnertextbox.js

```
var spinner = require('../pages/ spinnertextbox.js');
var home = function () {

var upArrow = element(by.xpath('’));


var downArrow = element(by.xpath(''));


this.spinfn = function (fun) {

    var spin = new spinner();

    switch (fun) {

        case 'uparrowclick':
            spin.Up(upArrowt);
            break;
        case 'downarrowclick':
            spin.Down(downArrow);
            break;
    }

};

};

module.exports = home;
```

And finally my test spec

Home.spec.js

```
var home = require('../pages/HomePage.js');

describe('reusability functionality : ', function () {


    it('reusability: ', function () {

        var hm = new home ();

//call to some other function in home page then 

        hm.spinfn('txtclick');
        d hm isplaySrc.spinfn('uparrowclick');
        hm.spinfn('downarrowclick');



    });


});
```

Is this approach acceptable or I’m totally in the wrong direction.